# Subset sum (Coin change)

Tags: c++, algorithm

My problem is, I need to count how many combination of array of integers sums to a value `W`.`

let say:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

My Algorithm is just find all combinations of lengths from `1` to `W / minimum(array)`, which is equal to `W` because minimum is 1.
And checking each combination if its sum equal to W then increment a counter `N`.

any other algorithm to solve this ? should be faster :)

**Update:**
ok, the subset problem and the Knapsack Problem are good, but my problem is that the combinations of the array repeats the elements, like this:

```
1,1,1 -> the 1st combination
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,1,5
1,2,2 -> this combination is 1,2,2, not 1,2,1 because we already have 1,1,2. 
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,3,3 -> this combination is 1,3,3, not 1,3,1 because we already have 1,1,3. 
1,3,4
.
.
1,5,5
2,2,2 -> this combination is 2,2,2, not 2,1,1 because we already have 1,1,2. 
2,2,3
2,2,4
2,2,5
2,3,3 -> this combination is 2,3,3, not 2,3,1 because we already have 1,2,3.
.
.
5,5,5 -> Last combination
```

these are all combinations of `{1,2,3,4,5}` of length 3. the subset-sum problem gives another kind of combinations that I'm not interested in.

so the combination that sums to `W`, lets say `W = 7`,

```
2,5
1,1,5
1,3,3
2,2,3
1,1,2,3
1,2,2,2
1,1,1,1,3
1,1,1,2,2
1,1,1,1,1,2
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

**Update:**
The Real Problem is in the repeated of the elements `1,1,1` is need and the order of the generated combination are not important, so `1,2,1` is the same as `1,1,2` and `2,1,1` .

Comment: Where is the sum to W factor comes in the example? :|

Comment: I don't see you mention W nowhere in your example, can you refer to it in the example please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No efficient algorithm exist as of now, and possibly never will (NP-complete problem).

This is (a variation of) the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: @RamiJarrar What does `0,2,2` mean?

Comment: this is in case the `array = {0,1,2,3,4}` , and 0,2,2 is not the end it continues i'll edit that ,

Comment: @RamiJarrar still don't know what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: its one of combinations for the array, i generate all combinations then i check which one is sum to W, but how could i get the count of combinations that sum to W from subset-sum problem ??

Comment: This is *not* a variation of the subset-sum problem unless the integers in the OP's array can be negative. To be fair, the OP does not say "an array of positive integers", but it seems from his description of how he intends to solve the problem that that is what he meant.

Comment: @rici if the numbers are negative, it is the subset sum problem. If not, it can be turned into it, by substracting a constant from all the numbers. That's why it's a variation.

Answer (score 3):

This is [coin change problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change). It could be solved by dynamic programming with reasonable restrictions of W and set size

Answer (score 0):

Here is code, in Go, that solves this problem.  I believe it runs in O(W / min(A)) time.  The comments should be sufficient to see how it works.  The important detail is that it can use an element in A multiple times, but once it stops using that element it won't ever use it again.  This avoids double-counting things like [1,2,1] and [1,1,2].

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sort"
)

// This is just to keep track of how many times we hit ninjaHelper
var hits int = 0

// This is our way of indexing into our memo, so that we don't redo any
// calculations.
type memoPos struct {
  pos, sum int
}

func ninjaHelper(a []int, pos, sum, w int, memo map[memoPos]int64) int64 {
  // Count how many times we call this function.
  hits++

  // Check to see if we've already done this computation.
  if r, ok := memo[memoPos{pos, sum}]; ok {
    return r
  }

  // We got it, and we can't get more than one match this way, so return now.
  if sum == w {
    return 1
  }

  // Once we're over w we can't possibly succeed, so just bail out now.
  if sum > w {
    return 0
  }

  var ret int64 = 0
  // By only checking values at this position or later in the array we make
  // sure that we don't repeat ourselves.
  for i := pos; i < len(a); i++ {
    ret += ninjaHelper(a, i, sum+a[i], w, memo)
  }

  // Write down our answer in the memo so we don't have to do it later.
  memo[memoPos{pos, sum}] = ret
  return ret
}

func ninja(a []int, w int) int64 {
  // We reverse sort the array.  This doesn't change the complexity of
  // the algorithm, but by counting the larger numbers first we can hit our
  // target faster in a lot of cases, avoid a bit of work.
  sort.Ints(a)
  for i := 0; i < len(a)/2; i++ {
    a[i], a[len(a)-i-1] = a[len(a)-i-1], a[i]
  }
  return ninjaHelper(a, 0, 0, w, make(map[memoPos]int64))
}

func main() {
  a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
  w := 1000
  fmt.Printf("%v, w=%d: %d\n", a, w, ninja(a, w))
  fmt.Printf("Hits: %v\n", hits)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put this to bed, here are recursive and (very simple) dynamic programming solutions to this problem. You can reduce the running time (but not the time complexity) of the recursive solution by using more sophisticated termination conditions, but the main point of it is to show the logic.

Many of the dynamic programming solutions I've seen keep the entire N x |c| array of results, but that's not necessary, since row i can be generated from just row i-1, and furthermore it can be generated in order left to right so no copy needs to be made.

I hope the comments help explain the logic. The dp solution is fast enough that I couldn't find a test case which didn't overflow a long long which took more than a few milliseconds; for example:

```
$ time ./coins dp 1000000 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3563762607322787603

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.012s
```

---

```
// Return the number of ways of generating the sum n from the
// elements of a container of positive integers.
// Note: This function will overflow the stack if an element
//       of the container is <= 0.
template<typename ITER>
long long count(int n, ITER begin, ITER end) {
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  else if (begin == end || n < 0) return 0;
  else return
      // combinations which don't use *begin
    count(n, begin + 1, end) +
      // use one (more) *begin.
    count(n - *begin, begin, end);
}

// Same thing, but uses O(n) storage and runs in O(n*|c|) time, 
// where |c| is the length of the container. This implementation falls
// directly out of the recursive one above, but processes the items
// in the reverse order; each time through the outer loop computes
// the combinations (for all possible sums <= n) for sum prefix of
// the container.
template<typename ITER>
long long count1(int n, ITER begin, ITER end) {
  std::vector<long long> v(n + 1, 0);
  v[0] = 1;
  // Initial state of v: v[0] is 1; v[i] is 0 for 1 <= i <= n.
  // Corresponds to the termination condition of the recursion.

  auto vbegin = v.begin();
  auto vend = v.end();
  for (auto here = begin; here != end; ++here) {
    int a = *here;
    if (a > 0 && a <= n) {
      auto in = vbegin;
      auto out = vbegin + a;
      // *in is count(n - a, begin, here).
      // *out is count(n, begin, here - 1).
      do *out++ += *in++; while (out != vend);
    }
  } 
  return v[n];
}
```